# Android app using webview gives html code on button click of url

Tags: android, httpclient, android-webview

I want to develop an android application that would open a url in a webView, using shouldInterceptRequest method in webViewClient.  I must get the data using HttpClient. So I built the application but as I run the application, the main.xml gets loaded and then when I click on the button it gives html code of the url.

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonurl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="visit     www.stackoverflow.com"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

webview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/webView1"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"/>
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name="MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".WebViewActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <!--    <data android:mimeType="image/png" /> -->
        </intent-filter>


    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

MyActivity.java

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {


private Button button;

//String strURL="www.facebook.com";


/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final Context context=this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonurl);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,WebViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });



}
}
```

WebViewActivity.java

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.webkit.WebView;
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity{

  String url="http://www.stackoverflow.com";
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    WebView webView=  (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    //MyWebViewClient myWebViewClient=new MyWebViewClient();
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    webView.loadUrl(url);

   // myWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView,url);



}
}
```

MyWebViewActivity.java

```
package com.example;

import android.webkit.WebResourceResponse;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;


public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

                    public InputStream httpcall(WebView view,String url) {


                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.stackoverflow.com");

                    BufferedReader reader = null;
                    String result = null;
                    try {
                        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
                        result = "";



                        reader = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                        response.getEntity().getContent()
                                )
                        );

                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            result += line + "\n";
                        }
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } finally {
                        if (reader != null) {
                            try {
                                reader.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( result.getBytes());

                        return byteArrayInputStream;

                    //String webData = result.toString();

                     //   return webData;
                    //view.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.stackoverflow.com", webData, "text/html", "UTF-8", "about:blank");


                }



    @Override
   public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,String url){

       return new WebResourceResponse("text/json","utf-8",httpcall(view,url));
   }







}
```

Comment: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18484): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.WebViewActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class webview
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)

Comment: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class webview
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.webview
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)

Comment: @sundeep Post your latest error logcat also in your question.

Comment: INFO/ActivityManager(356): START {cmp=com.example/.WebViewActivity u=0} from pid 20704
09-10 05:46:01.102: INFO/ActivityManager(356): Displayed com.example/.WebViewActivity: +108ms
09-10 05:46:01.132: ERROR/dalvikvm(20704): Class lookup Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse; attempted with exception pending
09-10 05:46:01.132: INFO/dalvikvm(20704): at com.example.MyWebViewClient.httpcall(MyWebViewClient.java:44)
09-10 05:46:01.132: INFO/dalvikvm(20704): at com.example.MyWebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest(MyWebViewClient.java:94)

Comment: WARN/ActivityManager(356): Force removing ActivityRecord{41ed4258 com.example/.WebViewActivity}: app died, no saved state
 WARN/InputDispatcher(356): channel '42529778 com.example/com.example.WebViewActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
 ERROR/InputDispatcher(356): channel '42529778 com.example/com.example.WebViewActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Comment: WARN/InputDispatcher(356): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '42529778 coINFO/WindowState(356): WIN DEATH: Window{42529778 com.example/com.example.WebViewActivity paused=false}INFO/WindowManager(356): WINDOW DIED Window{42529778 com.example/com.example.WebViewActivity paused=false}

Comment: @sundeep you are testing this application on which API?

Comment: @DipakKeshariya android version 4.1.1

Comment: @sundeep then add this two line after setcontentview(R.layour.webview) , StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

Comment: @DipakKeshariya  sorry bro that doesn't help it's the same....

Comment: @DipakKeshariya I have updated the question can you check it once...

Comment: @sundeep it is completely working here, what's the problem?

Comment: @DipakKeshariya when i am running the app on API 11 or greater devices the button click gives me plain html code with tags.... devices like google nexus....

Comment: @sundeep Here I checked your full code and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Add this `setContentView(R.layout.webview);` line into your WebViewActivity class before `WebView webView=  (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);` and write  instead of , it will solve your problem.

and change below line of your activity.

```
String url="http://www.stackoverflow.com"
```

Comment: thanks for the solution somehow i missed it, i made the changes but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: @sundeep Change in your webview.xml file <webview> to <WebView>, it will solve your problem.

Comment: @DipakKeshariya thanks.. that works... the application does not close but Still the web page is not loading....

Comment: @sundeep check your internet connection.

Comment: @DipakKeshariya i have checked that. I am able to browse the internet on my device... i also gave use internet permission in manifest file...

Comment: @DipakKeshariya Now the app closes after i click on the button....previously it used to give page cannot be loaded or check you connectivity....

Comment: @sundeep Update your question and post your code into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think `webView` is **null** In your **WebViewActivity**

Because you forgot to call `setContentView(R.layout.webview);` in onCreate();

Something like,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    WebView webView=  (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    //MyWebViewClient myWebViewClient=new MyWebViewClient();
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl(url);
   // myWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView,url);
}
```

Comment: oh that was a big mistake i made. Thanks for the solution but that doesn't solve the problem.